# How does a Cordova app build know what CodePush environment is applicate?

Tags: code-push

I have a `CodePush` app that has three deployments: *testing*, *staging* and *production*.

I have different app builds that align with these:

- A build that does out to testers (testing)
- A build that goes out to a group of preview users (staging)
- A production build (production).

How does `CodePush` know what deployment it should be sending to a build?

And how do I set up my app to make sure the right build (e.g. staging version of app) is getting the right deployment (e.g. staging deployment in `CodePush`)?

Answer (score 1):

The CodePush server knows which deployment you want to query for updates against based on the deployment key which is configured in the `config.xml` file or is passed to the call to `sync` (with the later taking precedence). If you want to generate three separate builds for QA/staging/production, then you simply need to make sure you update the deployment key that is set in your `config.xml` file before running `cordova build` to generate the APK or IPA file.

Unfortunately, Cordova doesn't really have a standard way of defining multiple environments, which would allow you to add your per-environment keys to the `config.xml` and have the right one be selected when doing an environment-specific build.

Depending on how your app is structured, you could also skip the `config.xml` file completely, and just pass the deployment key directly to the call to `sync()`. Then, you just need to make sure your app defines all the neccesary keys in a config somehow and loads the correct one for each build. You can take a look at this [starter project](https://github.com/mwaylabs/generator-m-ionic/blob/master/docs/guides/environments.md) for an idea of how this could be generally done.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I'm using checkForUpdate() instead of sync() but I see from the docs that both will accept an arg for deployment key. The background to this question is working out how to get the promotion of releases working. Since our builds know what kind they are (test, staging, or production) it will be pretty straight forward for me to pass the appropriate deployment key with checkForUpdate()

Comment: Awesome! I would love to chat more about your per-environment build setup. Email me at joncart@microsoft.com if you'd be up for syncing on it. It would be really insightful for our team to see how you're doing it. Thanks!

Comment: @onblur will you add an answer to this question about how to set multiple environments in cordova, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have configured CodePush for my dev, test and prod environments. But my application is a react-native one. I think the same will works for Cordova as well.

The important point is CodePush identify particular app by it's `CodePushDeploymentKey`. First you should create 3 channels on AppCenter for dev, test and prod. Then setup CodePush on those 3 environments and Get relevant CodePushDeploymentKeys.

Then you have to add those 3 keys for 3 different targets on your app. For iOS you can create 3 different targets on Xcode with 3 different plist files and add those different CodePush keys in relevant plist files.

For android you can create 3 different Product Flavors for dev, test and prod and then add DeploymentKeys on each flavor.

In this [article](https://medium.com/@katramesh91/how-to-configure-codepush-for-multiple-development-environments-ios-android-in-react-native-93f076f95952) I have explained everything step by step with all the screenshots and links.